# Yii объединение множества js файлов в один с использованием scriptMap

Tags: clientscript, php, yii

Привет всем! 
Взялся за оптимизацию загрузки своего проекта в браузере клиента. 
У меня сейчас статически в шаблоне подключаются 12 .js файлов.
Хотчется их объединить в один. В документации нашел, как это делается ([здесь](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.performance)), но там пишут, что

> Нам понадобится использовать
> какой-либо инструмент для слияния (и,
> возможно, сжатия) JavaScript в один
> файл и записать результат в js/all.js.

А что именно использовать - не ясно. Недолго погуглив нашел [расширение](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/extendedclientscript/), внес в свой конфиг настройки, которые описаны в его документации, но все еще не ясно, как получить склеянный файл. Даже [эта тема на форуме](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=700) не внесла ясности

Кусок конфига приложения:

```
'clientScript' => array(
            'scriptMap' => array(
                'class' => 'ext.ExtendedClientScript.ExtendedClientScript',
                'combineCss' => true,
                'compressCss' => true,
                'combineJs' => true,
                'compressJs' => true,

                'jquery.min.js' => false,
                'jquery.js' => false,
                "/js/common.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/csschange.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/dialogue.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.cookies.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.jeditable.mini.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.jeditable.wysiwyg.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.placeholder.fix.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.ui-slider.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/jquery.wysiwyg.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/js.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/newmain.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/nolkaCommonPrinting.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/nolkaCustom.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/nolkaEventHandlers.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/nolkaTableTools.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/placechoose.js" => "/js/all.js",
                "/js/select.js" => "/js/all.js",
            ),
        ),
```

ПРи попытке достучаться до http://localhost/js/all.js вываливается 404 ошибка. mod_rewrite включен.

Answer (score 1):

так почему не использовать

```
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->scriptMap=array(
    'jquery.js'=>'/js/all.js',
    'jquery.ajaxqueue.js'=>'/js/all.js',
    'jquery.metadata.js'=>'/js/all.js',
    …
);
```

***404 потому что файла такого у тебя на сервере нет, создай папку js в ней файл all.js и дай приложению права на запись.***

Yii же не может просто так взять и создать за тебя файл и вписать в него весь JS код, который ты указал. Дополнительного расширения не нужно, все отлично делается базовыми компонентами Yii

Comment: понятно, Я то думал, что он будем чем-то вроде алиаса для какой-то хитрой конструкции)

ps:// Мне нужно в конфиге это описать, а не в экшне)

Comment: Создал файл, дал права на запись, но он все-равно пуст.